# macOS Bash - Adding characters in front of file names with a specific extension in folders recursively using Bash

Tags: bash, macos, file, rename

I have to renamed files with a extension like ".abc" and add a prefix in front of it.

like "OldFileName.abc" to "AAA_OldName.abc".

The macOS files are actually folders with content inside them, like an application .app extension. Those folders are inside a top directory with several other directories.

How can I do that? I thought something like this:

```
find /Users/iPPi/PhotoLR -type d -iname '*.abc' |     while read d; do
  echo mv "$d" "AAA_${d%.abc}"
  mv "$d" "AAA_${d%.abc}"
done
```

This is wrong because it doesn't work and my Bash knowledge goes this far.
Thank you in advance for helping me out.

If my question is not clear enough please ask me to correct this.

Comment: Why are you using `${d%.abc}`? That removes the `.abc` extension.

Comment: So is the extension `.abc` or `.app`? Or is it both, like `something.abc.app`?

Comment: @Barmar, thats why I ask for advice. About your second post, .abc . And the .app was used as to make it clear that it was a folder underneat like an app with content s.

Comment: So you mean something like `Foo.app/filename.abc`?

Comment: No. Why  did you remove you latest answer. Did looks good.

Comment: It wasn't right. See my answer below.

Comment: Take a loot at the [relevant BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) too.

Comment: Be aware `mv` will overwrite existing files with the new name. You may want to test for that condition.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/030 (How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Answer (score 2):

you need to split the pathname into directory and filename, so you can put `AAA_` before just the filename.

```
find /Users/iPPi/PhotoLR -type d -iname '*.abc' |     while read -r d; do
    file=${d##*/}
    dir=${d%/*}
    newfile="$dir/AAA_$file"
    echo mv "$d" "$newfile"
    mv "$d" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Also maybe use `mv -v` instead of the separate `echo`; and for robustness probably favor `find -exec` over piping to `while read` (especially without `read -r`). See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: `find -exec` is a real PITA when you're executing multiple commands. You can exec `bash -c ...` but that gets complicated, so I would usually recommend putting the commands in a script and doing `-exec /path/to/script {} \;`. But in any case, the purpose of this answer was to show how to process the filename to perform the `mv`.

Comment: No objections there. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Something like `-execdir mv -v {} AAA{} \;` would work nicely here, though.

Comment: Feel free to post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific scenario,

```
find /Users/iPPi/PhotoLR -type d -iname '*.abc' -execdir mv {} AAA_{} \;
```

would avoid the hassle of explicitly splitting off the directory name, as in Barmar's answer. `-execdir` performs a command *in the directory where the item was found, on the base name of the item,* so `find` does basically all of the (not very) heavy lifting for you here.

This has additional robustness over a `find ... | while read -r` when it comes to file names with newlines in them etc; see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for (much) more on the topic.